# XML to PHP array issue - Columns being combined into a single Row instead multiple rows

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach, simplexml

I have gone through all of the previous questions and cannot find a solution that works.  I have not worked with XML in the past and I am feeling a bit confused.  I am aware that when printing simplexml you do not see all the data, but I cannot get the data to end up the way I want it.

The data I have collected from a CURL request that returns only XML is the following:

```
<result>
  <header>
    <col>
      <label>Account Id</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Employee Id</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Username</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>First Name</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Last Name</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>New Status</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Old Status</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Changed</label>
    </col>
    <col>
      <label>Email</label>
    </col>
  </header>
    <body>
      <row>
      <col>4346088504</col>
      <col>6534</col>
      <col>Nalini.LastName</col>
      <col>Nalini</col>
      <col>LastName</col>
      <col>Terminated</col>
      <col>Active</col>
      <col>02/01/2019 12:58p</col>
      <col>email1</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>32103136</col>
      <col>2835</col>
      <col>Karen.LastName</col>
      <col>Karen</col>
      <col>LastName/col>
      <col>Inactive</col>
      <col>LOA</col>
      <col>02/01/2019 07:27a</col>
      <col>email2</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>4348430099</col>
      <col>6652</col>
      <col>elouise.LastName</col>
      <col>Elouise</col>
      <col>LastName</col>
      <col>Active</col>
      <col>LOA</col>
      <col>02/01/2019 07:20a</col>
      <col>email3</col>
    </row>
  </body>
 <footer/>
</result>
```

This is returned as a string and saved in the variable $result as follows

```
$result = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
$result = $result->body;
```

Without going into a long tangent I have tried many different iterations/loops to get this to the following structure with all the fields not just the example ones I have typed:

```
           $result = array(
                'employees' => array(
                    array(
                        'KronosUniqueID' => '4346088504',
                        'KronosID' => '6534',
                        'FirstName' => 'Nalini',
                        'LastName' => 'LastName'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'KronosUniqueID' => '32103136',
                        'KronosID' => '2835',
                        'FirstName' => 'Karen',
                        'LastName' => 'LastName'
                    )
                    array(
                        'KronosUniqueID' => '4348430099',
                        'KronosID' => '6652',
                        'FirstName' => 'Elouise',
                        'LastName' => 'LastName'
                    )
                )
            );
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.  The final output can be an object as well if that is preferable.

Comment: You're going to need to build loops to "import" your XML regardless, I'd recommend you include your work so far so we can help.

Comment: Do you want the labels from the XML or are you translating them into your own labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic implementation to extract the data, Since you are re-labeling the fields, you're going to have to do this manually. Expand on the mapping to capture the data you want.

```
$simpleXML = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$output = array();
foreach( $simpleXML->xpath('//body/row') as $row )
{
  $output[] = array(
    'KronosUniqueID' => (int) $row->col[0],
    'KronosID' =>  (int) $row->col[1],
    'FirstName' => (string) $row->col[3],
    'LastName' => (string) $row->col[4],
  );
}
```

---

Here is an "automatic" version using the labels with label correction.

```
$simpleXML = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

$labels = (array) $simpleXML->xpath('//header/col/label');
$labels[0] = 'KronosUniqueID';
$labels[1] = 'KronosID';
$labels = array_map( function( $string ){ return str_replace( ' ', '', $string ); }, $labels ); // removes space character

$output = array();
foreach( $simpleXML->xpath('//body/row') as $row )
{
  $output[] = array_combine( $labels, (array) $row->col );
}
```

Comment: I've added a second version to show how you could process the labels too

Comment: Note that you don't really need XPath here unless you really love it: `$simpleXML->xpath('//body/row')` in this case is just the same as `$simpleXML->body->row`, and `$simpleXML->xpath('//header/col/label')` could be replaced with `$simpleXML->header->col` and then `function($col) { return whatever($col->label); }`

Comment: Yeah this is true, I was distilling my code down as I was improving it and forgot to simplify the data selection, thanks for the input @IMSoP